# Can I overload an == operator on an Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, equality, iequatable

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
  int A {get;}
  int B {get;}
}
```

and I have multiple classes implementing IFoo.
I want to check equality, not based on ReferenceEquality, but two IFoos should be considered equal, if both A and B is the same (in reality I'm checking a collection of Key-Value pairs sent through WCF, that is why I can't have ReferenceEquality).
Now if I have:

```
IFoo first = new FooBar1() { A = 1, B = 1};
IFoo second = new FooBar2() { A = 1, B = 1};
if (first == second) {
 //this should return true
}
```

Currently `IFoo` is `IEquatable<IFoo>`, so FooBar1 and FooBar2 overrides `Equals(IFoo other)`, but that's not what gets called on ==. I'm hunting through my code to replace `a==b` with `a.Equals(b)` everywhere, but that's just not nice.

What can I do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, you can't. Overloading `==` requires static methods in one of the types you use, and an interface can't contain those. Extension methods can't help either. So on interfaces == is always using reference equality.

Note that `a.Equals(b)` will throw an exception if a==null.

Comment: yeah, for that I already wrote an EqualsWithNull extension, that returs true for a.EqualsWithNull(b)...

Comment: @TDaver or you could use `Object.Equals(a, b)`, which - since every type inherits Object - can be shortened to just `Equals(a, b)`

Answer (score 6):

No, you can neither overload an operator on an interface, nor ensure that any implementors do so (as operator overloading is static in C#
).

Your best option is what you've done, to make `IFoo` inherit from `IEquatable<IFoo>` and use `Equals(IFoo)`

Answer (score 3):

Besides [CodeInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066281/can-i-overload-an-operator-on-an-interface/5066300#5066300)' answer you may be interested in reading [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

Comment: But note that it says to overload `operator ==` and `operator !=` when the type is immutable. So have interface (multiple types same interface but different semantics all immutable) need to use abstract base rather than interface so I can override operators when other types return mixed collections. In the end: hitting limits of the CLR type system (again :-( ).

Answer (score -1):

Since introduction of C# 8 you can provide interfaces with default implementations and static methods (which allows you o define operators for interfaces)

More here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions

Comment: I was really interested in this, but the link is broken. Consider updating it -- also, when you post links to articles it's a good idea to paste a bit of the article into your answer so even if the article is taken down your answer is still valid.

Answer (score -2):

What you're talking about here is an implementation detail, a Interface should not (cannot) define how it is implemented.

Comment: You're not wrong, but your answer is closer to a comment.  This was not a 'why' question.  (Just a guess, I did not vote.)