# Testing for value equality between two interface instances in c#?

Tags: c#, interface, iequatable

So I have an interface, lets call it IInterface.

```
public interface IInterface : IEquatable<IInterface>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Number { get; }
    Task<bool> Update();
}
```

Then I try and implement the interface in Implementation.

```
    public bool Equals(IInterface other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;

        return (this.Name.Equals(other.Name) && this.Number.Equals(other.Number));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Number.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as IInterface ;
        return other != null && Equals(other);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Implementation left, IInterface right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null)) return false;

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Implementation left, IInterface right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
```

The problem I am running into is in a setter:

```
    public IInterface MyIntf
    {
        get { return _myIntf; }
        set
        {
            if (_myIntf == value) { return; }
            _myIntf = value;
        }
```

Intellisense is showing that the equality test there is testing the references only and treating both left and right as objects. I assume this is because there is no operator overload for ==(IInterface left, IInterface right). Of course, I cannot actually implement that function because == requires one of the sides to match the type of the implementing class. How does one properly make sure two interfaces can be checked for equality against each other?

**Update**

Got it, you cannot implement == for an interface. I will use Equals. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should explicitly call `Equals`:

```
if (_myIntf != null && _myIntf.Equals(value)) { return; }
```

Implementing `IEquatable<T>` does not impact the `==` operator.

Comment: Is it possible to implement an == operator overload for an interface?

Comment: A shorter way with the null propagation operator : `_myIntf?.Equals(value) ?? false`

Comment: @bodangly No, you can't. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066281/can-i-overload-an-operator-on-an-interface

Comment: @Fabien Right. I'm not used to C# 6 syntax yet. However, find it kind of a matter of personal taste, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Equals` instead of `==`:

```
public IInterface MyIntf
{
    get { return _myIntf; }
    set
    {
        if (_myIntf.Equals(value)) { return; }
        _myIntf = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the null propagation operator in case of  `_myIntf`is null : `_myIntf?.Equals(value) ?? false`

Comment: @Fabien So if I want to not allow null anywhere, could I actually use the null propagation operator to replace null with a NullObject Pattern?

Comment: @bodangly I juste pointed that if  `_myIntf` is null it can end in a NullReferenceException.