# Overloading an addition operator for a List using generic types

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, ienumerable

I tried to code something like this:

```
public static List<T> operator+<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
{
    return list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
}
```

It didn't work.

None of the questions I could find about "operator overloading with generics" were about extension methods. This question is not a duplicate because the other question doesn't mention generic types.

Comment: Essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066281/can-i-overload-an-operator-on-an-interface, but for a different operator. I do not believe that changes the answer.

Comment: If you search for "c# operator extension method" you should see it is simply not possible

Comment: @hvd That question has nothing to do with generic types.

Comment: @Backs Edited the question.

Comment: Please do not do this. Its bad enough that strings and delegates overload +

Comment: @Zephandrypus That other question doesn't mention generic types because generic types are irrelevant. It's equally impossible for generic and non-generic types.

Comment: @hvd Since when is there a non-generic List?

Comment: @EricLippert Why? Please explain. I'm not going to just take your word on it for no reason.

Comment: Zephandrypus if @EricLippert as one of language's designers says it is bad idea you may actually "take his word on it for no reason"... :)

Comment: @Zephandrypus You know damn well you didn't originally ask about `List<T>`. The edit history is visible to all. You originally asked about `IEnumerable<T>`, and the non-generic `IEnumerable` still exists today. Not only that, it doesn't make one iota of difference. The answer is the same for all types. To overload operators for a type, you need to add the operator as a method for that type. If you can't, whether it's a BCL type or not, whether it's generic or not, doesn't matter, the answer is you can't.

Comment: There are far too many reasons to explain all of them in a comment, but basically it comes down to "don't be cute".  People see operator overloading and then think "oh, I'll make `<<` mean *stream redirection* and I'll make `Order + Customer` produce `Invoice`..." and so on. What we end up with is code that is comprehensible only to the original author, and which abuses our intuitions about the meanings of operators. Arithmetic operator overloading should be used for *actually arithmetic types* and that's all.

Comment: Now, if you are in fact hell bent on doing this crazy thing, then what you have to do is create your own type, create an addition operator on that type, and then create a conversion operator on that type from lists to your type. But again, please do not. If you wish to express the concatenation of two sequences to form a third, we already have that, as you know: `seq1.Concat(seq2)` is nicely concise. It's already the right thing to do. Don't mess with it.